# Can't rebuild my application anymore

Tags: c#, rebuild

I'll give you 2 versions of my problem to describe it, first the short version.

When I try to build my application it does that perfectly and my app works but when I try to rebuild it, that fails and gives an error message saying that 2 files are missing (bin/debug/MusicPlayer.exe and bin/debug/MusicPlayer.pdb). When I then try to build normally, it fails to with the same error.

Now the longer version:
The way this happened was quite out of nowhere, I program on 2 different locations (both in Visual Studio 2010 sp1) but to always have the recent version in the right place I copy the entire solution folder to a usb stick, this folder I copy over again on the other PC and use it to continue were I left off, I've done this many times without problem. Yesterday however, I got an exception while testing the app. But instead of showing this in my code, it was complaining that it could not find the program.cs file (it was there, but apparently it had a different checksum (md5) and it asked me to use this one. After a while I found what part of my code caused the exception and fixed it. Since then I haven't got that error anymore. But when I later tried to rebuild instead of build, it gave me the error described in the short version. I have tried to fix it, but apparently I was not very successful.

Basically, what I think it does is delete the files in the debug folder that need rebuilding and then gives me the error of missing files (the files that it deleted) and thus failing to rebuild succesfully because these deleted files the normal build option won't work to.
(What I then do is re-copy them from my usb to make the normal build work).
Don't know if it's important, but I program in C# and I'm still learning.
Also when I copied it to my usb I believe I had no errors and the app was working fine (except the part I fixed later, which I could not test at that location). And when I build the entire solution it gives some warning ==> "Assembly 'bun/debug/MusicPlayer.exe' is incorrectly specified as file" and this for 5 files.

Does anyone know how to fix this rebuild problem and if necessary the warnings?
Thanks in advance
(and sorry for my bad English)

Comment: I once accidentially added my own assembly as a reference leading to a circular reference (actually the bloody VS.NET WinForms designer did this...) which resulted in similar issues. Removing the assembly from the own references solved the issue.

Comment: I don't have the project in the reference list so that's not causing the problem with my project  i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it seems like you might be confusing yourself with your directory structure here. If you want to add Content or Resources (Images, Text Files, etc.) you should place them in a folder within your project (not called bin or obj). All your build files will go here. Instead place the Content in another folder and Right Click -> Properties and Set the build action to "Content" or "Resource" and set the Copy to Output Directory (bin folder) to "Do not Copy" or "Copy if newer."

The project is **failing** because you have the built executable "MusicPlayer.exe" in your project. So Visual Studio is trying to build an executable file in adding to the project. Restructure your directories or remove "MusicPlayer.exe" ever time your build your project.

Comment: Yeah it's definitly a bin folder :p, the file exists before i rebuild and i also have the bin folder on my usb (i use it as backup cuz the rebuild removes the files (wich i put back there in order for the normal build to work))

Comment: If you want anyone to take a look for you post a link to your project.

Comment: I dont think the problem is in my code (the app works fine, also a normal build works) i think the problem is with visual studio 2010

Comment: I 100% doubt that. Your doing something wrong when you transfer files back and forth. If you post a build the doesn't work I can figured out why.

Comment: I've uploaded my entire solution to megaupload here's the link: http://www.megaupload.com/?d=93686GNS

Comment: Thank you verry much, this resolved my problem, i have relocated my resources folder and corrected the refrences of these files to their new location. i also set te copy to output to "copy if newer" like you said. now i can rebuild again. Thanks again for all your help and time.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it works and I hope you learned a thing or two

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any anti-virus software running? They can go way too aggressive on removable drives. You are actually continuously deleting and creating a runnable program on usb stick by recompiling.

Just a guess tho...

Comment: i have antivirus running (microsofts security essentials and mallwarebytes) but they are not the problem also i'm not working directly on my usb, i copy the files to my Harddrive and work from there (so i can remove the usb)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you have a pre- or post-build event with a hardcoded path in it. Fix that using variables and it should be ok.